# Solr reload does not affect synonym file

Tags: solr

I am using solr 7.3.1 and solr reload does not change synonyms.txt and managed-schema files. To reproduce this problem, I have followed these steps:

1. I downloaded solr-7.3.1.zip file from site and unzipped the file in the same folder.
2. By using this command, I have started solrcloud and added new collection without errors.(Using Ubuntu 16.04)

   `bin/solr start -e cloud -noprompt`
3. When I write "aaafoo" in analyzer of gettingstarted in Solr Admin Panel, SGF part retuns "aaabar".(Because this rule is in default synonyms.txt file) I selected _text_ field type.
4. I changed this "aaafoo => aaabar" line to "aaafoo => aaabbb" in solr/configsets/_default/conf/synonyms.txt and reloaded core by using collections section in Admin Panel. The reload button was green after some time.
5. The result is same as in 3 when I type "aaafoo" in analyzer. It should return "aaabbb" but it is still "aaabar". synonyms.txt file is unchanged in admin panel, too.

Thanks.

Comment: does your configset directory has a directory other then _default like your collection name may be ?

Comment: -noprompt uses default configuration and default collection names. Default collection name which is suggested by solr is gettingstarted and the configuaration set is _default.

Answer (score 0):

Just reloading the core does not do it because you have to upload the changes to the Zookeeper that is holding the configset as you are in cloud mode.

Your instance uses the configset on disk to feed it into Zookeeper and then works with Zookeeper, which it watches for changes.

The collection reload is needed to pick up synonym changes, that part is correct.